# What does mean for loop with one semicolon?

Tags: javascript, ecma, ecmascript-2024

Can please someone give an example of third `for loop` [from specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-for-statement) and explain what does it mean?

> **14.7.4 The for Statement**
>
> - **Syntax**
>
>   - ForStatement<sub>[Yield, Await, Return]</sub> **:**
>
>     - **for (** [lookahead ≠ **let [**] Expression<sub>[~In, ?Yield, ?Await] opt</sub> **;** Expression<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await] opt</sub> **;** Expression<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await] opt</sub> **)** Statement<sub>[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return]</sub>
>     - **for ( var** VariableDeclarationList<sub>[~In, ?Yield, ?Await]</sub> **;** Expression<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await] opt</sub> **;** Expression<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await] opt</sub> **)** Statement<sub>[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return]</sub>
>     - **for (** LexicalDeclaration<sub>[~In, ?Yield, ?Await]</sub> Expression<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await] opt</sub> **;** Expression<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await] opt</sub> **)** Statement<sub>[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return]</sub>

Comment: @MisterJojo Do you mean [them](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements)?

Comment: @MisterJojo We don't have any semicolons in `for of` loop

Comment: `for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)` is an example of the third. The LexicalDeclaration has a `;` in its production

Comment: @NickParsons Oh, thanks, didn't noticed that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `LexicalDeclaration`, you can see it [is defined as](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#prod-LexicalDeclaration):

- LexicalDeclaration<sub>[In, Yield, Await]</sub> **:**

  - LetOrConst BindingList<sub>[?In, ?Yield, ?Await]</sub> **;**

So all three cases of `for` loops have two semicolons. Lexical declarations are not expressions and so they have chosen to include the semicolon in *its* definition, rather than following every use of LexicalDeclaration with **;**.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

- `let i = 0;` is the **Lexical Declaration**
- `i < 5` is the condition checked before each iteration
- `i++` is executed after each loop iteration

Comment: But you used 2 semicolons

Comment: You was too close) You should write `let i = 0;` is the **Lexical Declaration**